# Specify parameters to an injected class in asp.net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

My problem is that I'm trying to pass to the constructor of a custom service some configurations keys that reside in my appsettings.json at the startup time. I want to know how can I achieve this.

This is my setup:

This is the interface for the email service

```
public interface IEmailService
{
   Task<bool> SendEmailAsync(string email, string subject, string message);
}
```

This is the interface for the parameters that are in the config file

```
public interface IAWSCredentialsConfig
{
    string AccessKeyId { get; }
    string SecretAccessKey { get; }
}
```

An this is the constructor of the implementation of the email service:

```
public EmailService(IAWSCredentialsConfig config)
{
      _config = config;

      ClientConfig = new AmazonSimpleEmailServiceConfig
      {
           RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USEast1
      };
}
```

How can I inject those two parameters into a Singleton instance of the EmailService?

Comment: read up here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration#use-options-and-configuration-objects

Comment: look specifically at the `IOptions<>` change your config to a class and use the `IOption` to inject it into your dependent class

Comment: Register your configuration as service with: `services.Configure<TYourSettingsClass>(Configuration.GetSection("YourSection"))` and pass it to your class constructor with `IOption<TYourSettingsClass>`.